# Simplify ratio of integrals $\frac{\int f(x-t) t e^{-t^2/2} dt}{\int f(x-t)e^{-t^2/2} dt}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, convolution

I am trying to simplify the following expression:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-t) t e^{-t^2/2} dt}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-t)e^{-t^2/2} dt}
\end{align*}

by getting it in terms of just one integral. For example, is the following possible

\begin{align*}
\frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-t) t e^{-t^2/2} dt}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-t)e^{-t^2/2} dt}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty y(x-t)g(t) dt
\end{align*}

for some function $y(t)$ and $g(t)$. Can we find $y,g$ in term of $f$ and $e^{-t^2/2}$?

Few comment:

1. observe that both integrals are convolutions
2. we can assume that both integrals exist and are finite
3. Can assume that $f(t)>0$ and $f \in L^1$

Would like to hear any suggestion or thoughts you can give me. Thank you

Comment: How could indefinite integrals be finite?

Comment: Sorry, I will add the limits.

Comment: Do you have any further information about the function $f$? Is it a probability function? If so, what kind?

Comment: The only information if that $f>0$ and $f \in L^1$. Yes, you can think of it as a pdf. My end goal (outside of scope of this question) is to solve for $f(t)$.  So, I can't give you more info.

Answer (score 3):

You might use:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-t) t e^{-t^2/2} dt = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-t) \frac{d}{dt} e^{-t^2/2} dt
$$
Upon integration by parts then:
$$
-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-t) \frac{d}{dt} e^{-t^2/2} dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dt} f(x-t) e^{t^2/2} dt \\
= -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} f(x-t) e^{-t^2/2} dt \\
= -\frac{d}{dx} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-t) e^{-t^2/2} dt
$$
Letting $ \widetilde{f}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-t) e^{-t^2/2} dt $, the original quantity is:
$$
-\frac{d}{dx} \log( \widetilde{f}(x) )
$$

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of this. As the matter of fact I started with the expression you have at the end. I have added a few new lines to clarify my question.

Comment: This is related to integral transforms and methods typically used in working on DE's.

Comment: I am not aware of this method. But would like to see what you mean. Is there a wiki link?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\int{f(x-t) t e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt}}{\int{f(x-t)e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt}}
$$

Let's consider this integral first:

$$
\int{f(x-t)e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt}
$$

Using integration by parts, we get

$$
\int{f(x-t)e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt} = F(x - t)e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} + \int{F(x - t)te^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt}
$$

where $F(x - t)$ is the anti-derivative of $f(x - t)$

Next, let's consider the top integral.

$$
\int{f(x-t) t e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt} = f(x - t)e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} + \int{f'(x - t)e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt}
$$

Depending on your function $f$, the following fraction may be easier to deal with:

$$
\frac{\int{f(x-t) t e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt}}{\int{f(x-t)e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt}} = \frac{f(x - t)e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} + \int{f'(x - t)e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt}}
{F(x - t)e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} + \int{F(x - t)te^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt}}
$$

Comment: Thank you very. Nice approach. But unfortunately it complicates matters for me. I added few lines to clarify my question please see.